# Unable to store alias C, while trying to use Python UDF in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs, pig-udf

My Python UDF code:

```
#commaFormat- format a number with commas, 12345-> 12,345
 @outputSchema("numformat:chararray")
 def commaFormat(num):
   return '{:,}'.format(num)
```

My Pig script:

```
DEFINE CSVExcelStorage org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage;
A = LOAD '/result.csv' using CSVExcelStorage() As (id:int,lastvisitedtime:chararray,title:chararray,typedcount:int,URL:chararray,visitcount:int,bytes:int);
B = limit A 15;
REGISTER '/data/pyudf/test.py' USING streaming_python AS myudfs;
C = FOREACH B generate myudfs.commaFormat($1);
```

Pig Stack Trace:

> --------------- ERROR 1002: Unable to store alias C
>
> org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable
>   to open iterator for alias C  at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:1019)    at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:747)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:376)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:206)
>     at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:81)     at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:630)    at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:176)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136) Caused by:
>   org.apache.pig.PigException: ERROR 1002: Unable to store alias C  at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:1122)     at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.store(PigServer.java:1081)   at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:994)     ... 13 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR
>   0: Exception while executing (Name: C:
>   Store(hdfs://localhost:54310/tmp/temp1063554930/tmp-651585063:org.apache.pig.impl.io.InterStorage)
>   - scope-16 Operator Key: scope-16): org.apache.pig.impl.streaming.StreamingUDFException: LINE : KeyError:
>   'concatMult4'
>
> at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.processInput(PhysicalOperator.java:314)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POStore.getNextTuple(POStore.java:159)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.fetch.FetchLauncher.runPipeline(FetchLauncher.java:157)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.fetch.FetchLauncher.launchPig(FetchLauncher.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.launchPig(HExecutionEngine.java:306)
>     at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1474)     at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1459)
>     at org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:1118)    ... 15 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.pig.impl.streaming.StreamingUDFException: LINE :
>   KeyError: 'concatMult4'
>
> at
>   org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.StreamingUDF$ProcessErrorThread.run(StreamingUDF.java:503)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you are missing () in your define statement.

```
REGISTER /path/piggybank.jar;
DEFINE CSVExcelStorage org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage();
```

You probably are using Mortar's cPython distribution which requires atleast pig0.12. Try using [jython](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/udf.html#register-python) script engine.

```
REGISTER '/data/pyudf/test.py' USING jython AS myudfs;
C = FOREACH B generate myudfs.commaFormat($1);
```

Alternatively,instead of writing a UDF you can easily remove the commas using the REPLACE function.

```
REGISTER /path/piggybank.jar;
DEFINE CSVExcelStorage org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage();
A = LOAD '/result.csv' using CSVExcelStorage() AS (id:int,lastvisitedtime:chararray,title:chararray,typedcount:int,URL:chararray,visitcount:int,bytes:int);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE id,REPLACE(lastvisitedtime,',',''),title,typedcount,URL,visitcount,bytes;
C = LIMIT B 15;
DUMP C;
```

Comment: Registering the python function using jython script engine fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

Pig does not handle for your Python UDFs which is bringing along dependent modules. 
And so you will need to wrap those in a JAR and register that file as part of your Pig script.

```
REGISTER '/data/pyudf/test.py' USING jython AS myudfs;
```

[Python UDFs explained](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-pig/9781449317881/ch10s04.html)